# Openssl error while installing paho-mqtt python package

Tags: python-3, software-installation, mqtt

I am trying to install `paho-mqtt` python library using below command:

`sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt`

But I am getting below openssl error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting paho-mqtt
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 321, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 428, in load_verify_locations
    self._ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 776, in load_verify_locations
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'no certificate or crl found')]
```

Error says `OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'no certificate or crl found')]`

I have installed `paho-mqtt` many times but never faced this issue. Can anyone please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by installing the certificates again:

1. sudo apt remove ca-certificates
2. sudo apt install ca-certificates
3. sudo reboot
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install python3-pip
6. sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt

Answer (score 0):

Just install `python3-paho-mqtt` which is in the repository!

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning the install may be done using `apt` instead of `pip`?

Comment: I actually resolved the issue by remove and installing the certificates again. Please check my answer